# How to update complex field programmatically and keep ability for updating?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

**I've tried to update this way**

```
$old_field = get_field( 'my-field', 'my-option-page' );

$my_field_structure = [
    'level-1' => [
        'level-1-1' => [
            'level-1-1-text' => 'Test 1'
        ]
    ],
    'level-2' => [
        'level-2-1' => [
            'level-2-1-text' => 'Test 2'
        ]
    ],
    // ... and so long
];

$old_field['level-1']['level-1-1']['level-1-1-text'] = 'Test 1 (Updated)';

update_field( 'my-field', $old_field, 'my-option-page' );
```

After this I've lost ability to update_field.

Field is always stay the same `'Test 1 (Updated)'`

Neither manual admin area nor programmatically I have no ability to update field value.

Value always stay the same `Test 1 (Updated)`

**How to properly update nested field and fix this issue?**

Comment: What are the key and values you want to update? How do they look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is **`max_input_vars`**
php.ini setting.

I've changed from `1000` to `5000` and the problem solved